# Returning Google My Business Information in a console application

Tags: c#, html, api

I have tried making a console app to add a random company name onto the end of a search and then return the HTML to extract the data. I would like to get this working on a true random basis but filtering by a random company name / postcode would be a start.

When adding on the name and postcode to the search call  such as "https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=**argos**+**LS15+9J**B&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b-ab&gfe_rd=cr&ei=OKu-V_3PE5CCaN74iMAG" the html returns no confirmation if the company has a google my business account. If I inspect element I can see the google my business information but if i return the html using the below call it doesn't return the right html I am looking for, can anyone help with this?

```
**using(WebClient client = new WebClient()) {
   string s = client.DownloadString(url);
}**
```

I am new to C#/ API so apologies in advance.

Answer (score 0):

google uses a lot of javascript to render the search result page. instead of trying to parse the result page, check [Google My Business API](https://developers.google.com/my-business/)